# rplidar A1 or Kinect Xbox One/360

Tags: ros, rplidar, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

which has better performance, autonomous navigation using rplidar A1 or Kinect Xbox one/360?

Has anyone made this comparison?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336794/rplidar-a1-or-kinect-xbox-one/360/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rplidar A1, because if the wider scan angle, and lower data rate. The algorithm works mutch better with those Gmapper Hecotr cartographer

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on 2019-11-04**:
I think kinect has a higher sample rate than Rplidar A1...

Is it better to have a larger scan angle than data rate? In case I am using AMCL ...

Angle_scan: A1(360º) > Kinect(57º)

Data_rate: Kinect > A1

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-11-05**:
Yes the scan angle is more important. The higher frame rate is only important if you like to drive realy fast.